# Why does GooglePlacesAPI autocomplete return establishments when other type is specified?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Here is the code:

```
function initializeAutocomplete(){
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchBox, {
        types: ['administrative_area3']
    });
};
```

I've tried every single type:

- geocode
- address
- (regions)
- (cities)

...and every single declaration returns establishments despite my specification.

In the documentation Google doesn't even say anything to the effect of "it **may** return this or that" as has been discussed in some other posts.

There is the following notification in the documentation, but I can't find any other information.

*Notice: The implementation for types in text search requests is changing. The types parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016, replaced by a new type parameter which only supports one type per search request. Additionally, the establishment, finance, food, general_contractor, grocery_or_supermarket, health and place_of_worship types will no longer be supported as search parameters (however these types may still be returned in the results of a search). Requests using the deprecated features will be supported until February 16, 2017, after which all text searches must use the new implementation.*

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a key such as  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=your-key"></script>`

Comment: @Visahan Here is what I'm using: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=my_key&libraries=places&callback=initializeAutocomplete" async defer></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: the property should be called `types`, not `type`.

```
function initializeAutocomplete(){
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchBox, {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
};
```

See the description of the `options` [in the Autocomplete guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) for more details.

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem. Establishments still show up despite the specification. @spiv

Comment: If you can truly get establishments when using `types: ['geocode']` please file a bug with a working code sample: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug